# Stopwatch Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stopwatch

I found this stopwatch tutorial online, however when i tried implementing it, it kept saying "TypeError: start is null" and "TypeError: h1 is undefined" in the console when i inspect the element. What is bugging me even further is that when i insert the code in here it works and if i put it into notepad++ it does not work. Is there a jquery file that i might have missed during the implementation and some how snippet is making it work?

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start" >start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery being used here so it's unlikely to be the culprit, unless you're using it elsewhere on the page.

Comment: But the snippet works...

Comment: Are you ensuring the code gets invoked on document ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all your code, including functions, in a comon function that you could name `initialize() { }`.

Then, put on your `<body>` tag the function binded `onload` event like following :

`<body onload="initialize()">`

This will tell your code not to execute unless the whole DOM and element have been created, because you can't access your elements unless they are all fully loaded.

Comment: In fact, you will use the functions you have in the script, this event is here to be sure all the element you will try to access are existing.

Comment: Yes, that answer works, but you are mixing your Javascript and HTML which just makes things more complicated and is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you have defined your Javascript BEFORE your HTML. Remember Javascript is a blocking language, so it will halt all operation (including loading the HTML) until the script is finished.

Move the script below your HTML or use some form of `$(document)ready`